# Possible to add HTML formatting (bold, italics) to string data cells in parse?

Tags: html, string, formatting

My app is reading text content from a string data cell in Parse. Is it possible to add HTML formatting to this text within Parse? Bold, italics, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add strings such as these when you are parsing?

```
<b> Defines bold text
<em> Defines emphasised text 
<i> Defines italic text
<small> Defines smaller text
<strong> Defines important text
```

An example of parsing a string can be found in the jQuery API Documentation at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: Your query is too vague to offer more assistance. Please consider editing with more details...